# three.js earth is not loading textures

Tags: javascript, three.js

I recently downloaded three.js and tried creating an earth in the universe. It's all working quite good, but when I try to put a texture on my Sphere, nothing happens, except, I'm not seeing the Sphere anymore...
I tried finding a solution here and on other websites, but nothing is working :-/

Please guys, help me. I ran out of ideas and this is making me going crazy :D

This is the code, where I'm stuck on:

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 32, 32);

var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
color: 0x4682B4,
map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('2_no_clouds_16k_002.jpg', {}),
bumpMap: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('elev_bump_16k_002.jpg'),
specularMap: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('water_16k_002.jpg'),
specular: new THREE.Color('grey')
});

var mesh = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
color: new THREE.Color('red'),
wireframe: true
});

var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
var earthMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mesh);
scene.add(sphere);
scene.add(earthMesh);

//--- Renderer --
function render
{
requestAnimationFrame(render);
sphere.rotation.y = + new Date() / 7000; //movement is added
renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

render();
```

Comment: Do you see errors in the browser console? (press F12)

Comment: What's the resolution of your textures? I've made the experience that too large textures didn't render e.g. on a laptop with bad or just moderate graphics card. Maybe you could try textures with lower resolution.

Comment: If `16k` is a reference to the resolution, that's not going to work like this.  Imagery layers need to be split up into tiles, [like Cesium does](http://cesiumjs.org/tutorials/Imagery-Layers-Tutorial/), so only the tiles relevant to the camera view are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I found out, why it didn't work.
First of all, the images were indeed too big. Also it was in jpg, which it just didn't want to work with (I don't know why...) Instead I used png.
Also it's working on my server, but not locally. Which I also don't know why :D Sometimes I think my computer has it's own mind... Like in iRobot :-D

Thank you guys for trying to help! You are the best <3
Cheers, Vicky